# Java 8: Lines Location occurrence, when filter is applied, stream, foreach

Tags: foreach, java-8, location, java-stream, lines

I don't know if is it possible:

I want to know the number line's where someWord is found in someFile.

```
   try {
      CharsetDecoder dec = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newDecoder()
          .onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
      try (Reader r = Channels.newReader(FileChannel.open("path"), dec, -1);
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(r)) {
        br.lines().filter(line -> line.contains("SomeWord"))
            .forEach(line -> System.out.println("location:" + line.????)); //Location where line has the "SomeWord"
      }
    } catch (IOException |java.io.UncheckedIOException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(RecursiveFolderAndFiles.class.getName())
          .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

How I can to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily need Stream for this or java-8... there is `LineNumberReader` that extends `BufferedReader`, so you could do:

```
LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(r)) {
   String line;
   while ((line = lnr.readLine()) != null) {  
       if(line.contains("SomeWord")) {
             System.out.println("location:" + lnr.getLineNumber())
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of piping further operations on the `br.lines()` you can collect to a list then utilize `IntStream.range` like so:

```
...
...
List<String> resultSet = br.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
IntStream.range(0, resultSet.size())
         .filter(index -> resultSet.get(index).contains("SomeWord"))
         .forEach(index -> System.out.println("location:" + index));
...
...
```

Now, you should have access to both the index and the lines.